# Using the TDocument class in Windows 7

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-5

I have an application written using C++ Builder 5 that uses the TDocument class. This class is part of the Preview ActiveX control, and uses shimgvw.dll.

It is automatically added as an option in the Borland "Import ActiveX Control" dialog in XP, however it is not an option in Windows 7.

How can I use this class with Windows 7?

Comment: Builder 5 is real old.  Can I recommend an upgrade.  I don't think Windows 7 was even a twinkle in someones eye when Builder 5 came out.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version of C++Builder.  On my Windows 7 machine, C++Builder XE2 (the latest version) does not display any kind of Document Preview object being present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a C++Builder problem.  C++Builder is merely displaying a list of the currently registered COM objects, whatever they happen to be.  If you are not seeing the Document object in the list, then shimgvw.dll is not registered/installed on Windows 7, that's all.  On my Windows 7 machine, C++Builder XE2 does not display any kind of Document Preview object being present, so it is not related to C++ Builder 5 specifically.